# Zipping a folder into equal size parts

Tags: zip, 7zip

I've been using 7Zip for a few years now and always liked that I could zip a folder into several parts of a specific size. For example, the website BOX only allows uploads under 100MB so anything I wanted to put into BOX, I just split the zip file into 95MB files. However, recently I've needed to do something similar except instead of breaking into a certain size, I need to split them up into a specific number of files but all equaling the same size. Right now, 7zip breaks them into the max size you allow and the last file is any remaining data ranging from 1KB up to the limit specified.

For example, say I have a 826MB file, I want it to zip up 5 files that are all the same size. Is there any program out there that will do this?

Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any program that does this, but if this is something that you're doing regularly, you could write a script that:

1. Finds out the size of the file
2. Calculates the maximum piece size to use if you want to split it into n pieces.
3. Constructs a corresponding 7zip command